# elasticsearch - find all words in specific field

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have document with field that contain 3 words.
I want to write a query that find documents where my search term have 100% of the words that exists in specific field.

examples:

the query will return the document
**term:** dog cat bird fox
**field:** dog bird fox

query will not return the document
because "fox" don't exists in the search term
**term:** dog bird
**field:** dog bird fox

I know that elastic have **minimum_should_match** ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html#query-dsl-minimum-should-match ) but it works only on the search terms.